# iframe added to wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, security

This page was added to one of my client's wordpress sites through an iframe. The URL clearly shows my client's website, but this content is not part of the site.

http://painlessbreastimplants.com/optionshouse-trading-platform

the site is a plastic surgeon website. please don't confuse it with porn or adult material

after receiving an email stating that my client is using optionshouse name without permission.

I used Sucuri scan to see what happened but no luck. Help Needed!

Answer (score 0):

Your site has code to call an iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

doMagic();
function doMagic() {
document.write('')
}

Comment: Hi Omnisite. Thank you for responding. I can't find where that is coming from

Comment: It looks like your site is using only pages, and there the iframe is not set, so I guess it is set only on posts. If you look at the code in single.php, do you see something with iframe? Or base64?

Comment: did you search all files for iframe or base64?

Comment: I am going to download the entire site. I don't know how to search all files inside the ftp or hosting account

Comment: Why don't you just remove that page/post, by the way?

Comment: that's the point... it doesn't exist. There is no page/post with that URL

Comment: Then I would also search for optionshouse-trading-platform in all files. Also in .htaccess